Nice bases for submodules of infinite free modules over a PID
It is a fact that given a finite rank free module $M$ over a PID and a submodule $N$, there exists some basis $\{m_1, \dots, m_k\}$ and ring elements $r_1 \mid \dots \mid r_j$ (for some $j \leq k$) such that $\{r_1 m_1, \dots, r_j m_j\}$ is a basis of $N$.
It is also a fact that every submodule of a free module over a PID is free.
My question is, can we say anything similar about the bases of $N \leq M$ when $M$ has infinite rank? If not, why not?

A standard proof of the first fact uses matrix manipulations to get the Smith Normal Form. Because it relies on this procedure being finite, it won't extend to infinite rank $M$. But a priori I don't see why it can't be true for infinite rank $M$ either.

The classification of submodules of a finite rank free module is equivalent to the structure theorem. Hence, we cannot expect it to be true in the infinite case.
Assume that $M$ is a free module with a submodule $N$ that have "nice" bases: There is a basis $B \subseteq M$, a subset $C \subseteq B$ and a function $r : B \to R \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\{r(b) \cdot b : b \in C\}$ is a basis of $N$. Then, the isomorphism $\bigoplus_{b \in B} R \to M$ induced by the basis maps $\bigoplus_{b \in C} r(b) R$ onto $N$. Therefore, the quotient $M/N$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of a free part $\bigoplus_{b \in B \setminus C} R$ and a torsion part $\bigoplus_{b \in B} R/r(b)R$. We see that $M/N$ is a direct sum of cyclic modules.
Now, every $R$-module is isomorphic to $M/N$ for some free $R$-module $M$ and some submodule $N$. Hence, the existence of nice bases would imply  that every $R$-module is a direct sum of cyclic modules. In particular, every torsionfree $R$-module would be free. This is of course wrong when $R$ is a PID that is not a field, consider the $R$-module $Q(R)$.
By the way, it is possible to classify the commutative rings such that every module is a direct sum of cyclic modules. They are precisely the Artinian principal ideal rings:

I. S. Cohen and I. Kaplansky, Rings for which every module is a direct sum of cyclic modules, in Cambridge, Mass. and Chicago, Ill. Mathematische Zeitschrift, Band 54, Heft 2, S. 97-101 (1951).

You can read that article here.
